# Python - Calling a function several times will change variable of different function instances

Tags: python, recursion

Let me explain by showing you the problematic code and its respective output:

```py
def find_amount_of(victim, key, value):
    def eval(v, k, dir, sc):
        hits = 0
        print("{}: {} -> {}".format(dir, k, v))
        
        # Currently only triggers when both have been hit
        if k == key or k == None:
            if v == value:
                hits += 1
        
        if type(v) == list or type(v) == dict:
            hits += second(k, v, hits, dir, sc)
        
        return hits
    
    def second(name, vv, hits, dir, sc):
        # Setup vars
        sc += 1
        hc = hits
        if name != "":
            dir.append(name)
        
        # Decide treatment of vv
        if type(vv) == dict:
            for k, v in vv.items():
                print("Second Counter: " + str(sc) + ", " + str(dir))
                hc += eval(v, k, dir, sc)
        elif type(vv) == list:
            for v in vv:
                hc += eval(v, None, dir, sc)
        
        # Return hits throughout entire thing
        return hc
    
    return second("", victim, 0, [], 0)

ex3 = {
    "1": {
        "1.1": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "2.1": 2
    }
}

print(find_amount_of(ex3, "1.3", 2))
```

Output:

```
Second Counter: 1, []
[]: 1 -> {'1.1': 1}
Second Counter: 2, ['1']
['1']: 1.1 -> 1
Second Counter: 1, ['1']
['1']: 2 -> {'2.1': 2}
Second Counter: 2, ['1', '2']
['1', '2']: 2.1 -> 2
0
```

What I don't understand is why *dir* has changed in the first instance of the *second* function call (Sorry for my terrible naming, this was just a quick test function i made).
When you look at the output, you can see the line "Second counter: 1, []". It's the first instance, and *dir* is just an emtpy list.
Now, a little later, the line "Second counter: 1, ['1']" triggers me. It's still the first instance, but for some reason *dir* has changed.
My first question is, why does it change when the *eval* function does not change the *second* function that called it?

My second question is: how can I fix this? Do I need a completely different approach?

Right now this codes purpose is to iterate through dicts and lists an to always keep track of where exactly it is.

Comment: Yes, sort out your naming not to use built-ins. dir always refers to the same instance of a list which second can change by appending to.

Answer (score 0):

I figuered it out.

Answer to the first question "Why?" is because python passes lists on by reference, and not by value.

Answer to the second question "How to fix?" is, to just pass a copy of the list instead of the actual list, like this:

```py
second(k, v, hits, dir.copy(), sc)
```

instead of this:

```py
second(k, v, hits, dir, sc)
```